# How to avoid using the subject of a sentence more than necessary

Tags: writing-style, paragraphs, writing-advice

My English grammar is rusty and I have not kept up with grammar rules. So, please bear with me as I struggled to frame the title of my question.
What I want accomplished is a paragraph that is short, sweet and that does not confuse the reader with repetitive detail. I get the feeling that my sentences below could be framed better. I have the following paragraph:

> To start building the system, begin with a phrase or one sentence summary that defines the system. “The Heat system models a two-dimensional heat diffusion experiment” This one-sentence summary characterizes your system.

I am going to be using the above paragraph in a Powerpoint slide. So, I want something that conveys the idea quickly. I am aware that I am using  some form of narrative (either first, second or third person?)

Any help in making it better is welcomed.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm having trouble understanding your paragraph. What is the relationship between the second sentence (in quotation marks) and the first and third sentences?

Comment: Okay. I will re-frame the paragraph.

Comment: I was meaning to say that the sentence in quotation marks is the "phrase or one sentence summary" alluded to in the first sentence. And I rephrased the third sentence to make the context clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use a phrase or sentence that defines the system to start building it.
>   For example, *This system models a two-dimensional heat diffusion
>   experiment*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to start with *"to start building."* (I'm assuming that you are refering to some sort of high-level system requirement, one that forms a frame of reference, to let the system developer(s) come to an understanding of what will be built.)

If I'm correct, that seems more like a *precursor* to building the system, rather than the actual start.  So, you might say,

> Before building the system, write a concise *system definition*.  For example:
>   • “The heat system models a two-dimensional heat diffusion experiment”